# Showing blank display after using Link tag in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my project I wanted to show products image  within Link tag  so that after clicking the image the i can show details about the product but I am getting blank page display after using Link or Navlink in ProductScreen

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Products from "../Product.js";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import ProductScreen from "./ProductScreen";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  {Products.map((product) => (
        <Col>
          <ProductScreen product={product} />
        </Col>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

**ProductScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductScreen = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Link>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={product.image} />
        </Link>

        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: The `Link` component is missing the `to` prop to link to anything. Is your app rendering any routes to link to? Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code you've an issue working with.

Comment: Silly me!! I forgot to add "to"

Thank you

Comment: Was that the issue or is there still something to resolve here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing `to` props in `<Link />` component, which should be delivered into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your  component in  tags. This way Link will work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).